# How to convert a PHP multi-dimensional array into another array based on a value within the original array(s)?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, output

I have spent a week on this, and I am trying to come up with a way to access the data in the multi-dimensional array and output it to another array, restructured differently, based on a value within the array. Rather than post rows and rows of broken code, I present my example simplified:

Here is the original array:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => array(2) {
        ["aaa"] => array(2) {
            ["a19a3234b881ce"] => array(2) {
                ["pid"] => int(29301)
                ["vid"] => int(29334)
                ["idx"] => int(88888)
            }
            ["a7aa94c38aa49caa"] => array(2) {
                ["pid"] => int(20568)
                ["vid"] => int(26547)
                ["idx"] => int(88888)
            }
        }
        ["bbb"] => array(2) {
            ["bsfn"] => string(4) "Apple"
            ["bsln"] => string(8) "AppleApple"
        }
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        ["aaa"] => array(3) {
            ["abd296a10"] => array(2) {
                ["pid"] => int(56734)
                ["vid"] => int(98612)
                ["idx"] => int(99999)
            }
            ["a31e920fde8"] => array(2) {
                ["pid"] => int(09800)
                ["vid"] => int(34521)
                ["idx"] => int(99999)
            }
            ["a7aa94c38aa49caa"] => array(2) {
                ["pid"] => int(20568)
                ["vid"] => int(26547)
                ["idx"] => int(99999)
            }
        }
        ["bbb"] => array(2) {
            ["bsfn"] => string(4) "Ball"
            ["bsln"] => string(8) "BallBall"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I want to output:

```
array(2) {
    ["88888"] => array(3) {
        ["a19a3234b881ce"] => array(4) {
            ["pid"] => int(29301)
            ["vid"] => int(29334)
            ["idx"] => int(88888)
            ["arr"] => string(14) "a19a3234b881ce"
        }
        ["a7aa94c38aa49caa"] => array(4) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(88888)
            ["arr"] => string(16) "a7aa94c38aa49caa"
        }
        ["bbb"] => array(2) {
            ["bsfn"] => string(4) "Apple"
            ["bsln"] => string(8) "AppleApple"
        }
    }
    ["99999"] => array(4) {
        ["abd296a10"] => array(4) {
            ["pid"] => int(29301)
            ["vid"] => int(29334)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["arr"] => string(9) "abd296a10"
        }
        ["a31e920fde8"] => array(4) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["arr"] => string(11) "a31e920fde8"
        }
        ["a7aa94c38aa49caa"] => array(4) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["arr"] => string(16) "a7aa94c38aa49caa"
        }
        ["bbb"] => array(2) {
            ["bsfn"] => string(4) "Ball"
            ["bsln"] => string(8) "BallBall"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort

Comment: #1: how are the arrays generated? do you have any control over it? 
#2: are the arrays you want to re-write are always in the "aaa"?

Comment: #1 - I have no control over the original array. It comes to me as a serialized array, and I unserialize() it. #2 Yes, they are always in [aaa]. The array keys inside of the [aaa] arrays are dynamically generated and there can any number of them. You'll note that in the desired output array, I need the data ordered by the idx value, and assign that value to each key.

Comment: Is there any rule behind that transformation? As you have already written the expected output, why not copy+paste it to your script?

Comment: @NicoHaase The idea is to take the original array data, place it into an array that is structured based on the [idx] value. Then, I will create a foreach loop that looks for each idx key and displays the data each key contains on a page and/or in an export file.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your quesiton by editing it. Also, please share you attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks Nico...I don't need help with the overall plan. I just need help converting the original array into the desired array. I've used a lot of nested foreach and spent hours looking over suggestions on this site on how to access the data and reformat it in the way I want. I am not able to make the connection. I just can't get it done, which is why I am reaching out. My attempts to solve the problem are literally tooo numerous to list.

Comment: It's impossible to provide help if you do not share what you've tried, as nobody can see where you are going wrong. Also, by providing only a single input array, there's no way for others to write such an algorithm on their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    if (!empty($item['aaa']) && is_array($item['aaa'])) {
        $key = array_values($item['aaa'])[0]['idx'] ?? null;
        if ($key) {
            $result[$key] = array_merge($item['aaa'], ['bbb' => $item['bbb'] ?? []]);
        }
    }
}

// Test result:
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Brilliant...that did EXACTLY what I wanted to do. Thank you so much for putting in the effort to help me get past this. However, I did change a few things up on my side based on your example.

Comment: See my comments for the changes. I will vote up as soon as I am able to.

Answer (score 0):

```
Final Output

array(5) {
    ["8888-81ce-4f15"] => array(5) {
            ["pid"] => int(29301)
            ["vid"] => int(29334)
            ["idx"] => int(88888)
            ["cky"] => string(8) "d9b04f15"
            ["arr"] => string(14) "a19a3234b881ce"
    }
    ["8888-9caa-8ac0"] => array(5) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(88888)
            ["cky"] => string(8) "fa71c3f5f8ac0"
            ["arr"] => string(16) "a7aa94c38aa49caa"
    }
    ["9999-6a10-dbb9"] => array(5) {
            ["pid"] => int(29301)
            ["vid"] => int(29334)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["cky"] => string(8) "e3fc1fdbb9"
            ["arr"] => string(9) "abd296a10"
    }
    ["9999-fde8-f409"] => array(5) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["cky"] => string(8) "88195c46f409"
            ["arr"] => string(11) "a31e920fde8"
    }
    ["9999-9caa-8ac0"] => array(5) {
            ["pid"] => int(20568)
            ["vid"] => int(26547)
            ["idx"] => int(99999)
            ["cky"] => string(8) "fa71c3f5f8ac0"
            ["arr"] => string(16) "a7aa94c38aa49caa"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the cky value, and created the unique array keys using the idx, cky, and arr values. The Final Output isn't exactly what I was hoping to get initially but it will do what I need it to do. I used the following to change the array keys:
        
        $nkeys = substr($item['idx'],-4) . '-' . substr($item['arr],-4) . '-' . substr($item['cky'],-4);

My final output was based on @user14717238 example code.

Comment: Correction: my final output was inspired by @user14717238's example code, not based on it exactly since@user14717238's is more like my initial output request and somewhat different than what I posted for my answer.